# How to create a custom base controller? is my code right?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

---

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
    private readonly IIdentityService _identityService;

    public BaseController(ApplicationDbContext context, IIdentityService identityService)
    {
        _context = context;
        _identityService = identityService;
    } 

    public BaseController()
    {
    }

     //reusable methods
     public async Task<Account> GetAccount()
     {
        //code to do something, i.e query database
     }


}
```

---

```
public class MyController : BaseController
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
    private readonly IIdentityService _identityService;

    public MyController(ApplicationDbContext context, IIdentityService identityService)
    {
        _context = context;
        _identityService = identityService;
    } 

    public async Task<IActionResult> DoSomething()
    {

      var account = await GetAccount(); 

      //do something

      Return Ok();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your base controller can be as is just remove the additional public call and convert the 2 private values to protected. Because you are extending BaseController from MyController, you dont need to re-instatiate the values, just call them. eg:

BaseController

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
    protected readonly IIdentityService _identityService;

    public BaseController(ApplicationDbContext context, IIdentityService identityService)
    {
        _context = context;
        _identityService = identityService;
    } 

     //reusable methods
     public async Task<Account> GetAccount()
     {
        //code to do something, i.e query database
     }


}
```

And your MyController

```
public class MyController : BaseController
{
    public async Task<IActionResult> DoSomething()
    {

      var account = await GetAccount(); 

      //do something and you can call both _context and _identityService directly in any method in MyController

      Return Ok();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Rest is fine as posted by @jonno but you need to modify the constructor in `MyController`:

```
public class MyController : BaseController
{
    public MyController(ApplicationDbContext context, IIdentityService identityService)
         :base(conext, identityService)
    {
    }
```